# How can I make the object rotate automatically when the user opens the application in SwiftUi?

Tags: swiftui, scenekit

It is possible to rotate it manually, but how do I get it to rotate automatically at a certain speed?

```
struct Home : View {
    
    @State var models = [
    
        Model(id: 0, name: "Venus", modelName: "AirForce.usdz"),       
    ]

 

    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
         
            SceneView(scene: SCNScene(named: models[index].modelName), options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl])
            // for user action...
            // setting custom frame...
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
             
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of ways - just rotate directly, or create a sequence of movements.  This example rotates some nodes back and forth, using duration for how fast you want it to go.

```
func resetRotation()
    {
        for (_, vNode) in displayNodes
        {
            vNode.node.removeAllActions()
        }
        vRotate0 = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 2)
        vRotate1 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(450)), z: 0, duration: 3)
        vRotate2 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90)), z: 0, duration: 1)
        vRotate3 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
        vRotate4 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45)), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
        
        seq = SCNAction.sequence([vRotate0, vRotate1, vRotate2, vRotate3, vRotate4, vRotate3, vRotate4])
        allSeq = SCNAction.repeatForever(seq)
        for (_, vNode) in displayNodes
        {
            vNode.node.runAction(allSeq)
        }
    }
```